# Concatenate backslash on python

Tags: python, concatenation, backslash

I'm new to python so forgive me if this sounds simple. I want to join a few variables to produce a path. Like this:

```
AAAABBBBCCCC\2\2014_04\2014_04_01.csv

Id + '\' + TypeOfMachine + '\' + year + '_' + month + '\' + year + '_' + month + '_' + day + '.csv'
```

How do I concatenate this? I putted single quotes around underline or backslash, but stackoverflow omits/modifies them.

Comment: Seems there are multiple ways to solve this, but I ended up using a modified sugestion from kojiro: r'{}\{}'.format('hi', 'bye') Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A backslash is commonly used to escape special strings. For example:

```
>>> print "hi\nbye"
hi
bye
```

Telling Python not to count slashes as special is usually as easy as using a "raw" string, which can be written as a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) by preceding the string with the letter 'r'.

```
>>> print r"hi\nbye"
hi\nbye
```

Even a raw string, however, cannot end with an odd number of backslashes. This makes string concatenation tough.

```
>>> print "hi" + r"\" + "bye"
File "<stdin>", line 1
print "hi" + r"\" + "bye"
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

There are several ways to work around this. The easiest is using string formatting:

```
>>> print r'{}\{}'.format('hi', 'bye')
hi\bye
```

Another way is to use a double-backslash in a regular string to escape the second backslash with the first:

```
>>> print 'hi' + '\\' + 'bye'
hi\bye
```

But all of this assumes you're facing a legitimate need to use backslashes. If all you're trying to do is construct Windows path expressions, just use `os.path.join`.

Answer (score 12):

You should use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to construct the path.

e.g:

```
import os
path = os.path.join(Id, TypeOfMachine, year + '_' + month, year + '_' + month + '_' + day + '.csv')
```

or if you insist on using backslashes, you need to escape them: as, so `'\\'`

Answer (score 5):

Normally, you'd *double* the backslash:

```
'\\'
```

Use `os.path.join()` to join directory and filename elements, and use string formatting for the rest:

```
os.path.join(Id, TypeOfMachine, '{}_{}'.format(year, month), 
             '{}_{}_{}.csv'.format(year, month, day))
```

and let Python take care of using the correct directory separator for your platform for you. This has the advantage that your code becomes portable; it'll work on an OS other than Windows as well.

By using string formatting, you also take care of any non-string arguments; if `year`, `month` and `day` are integers, for example.

Comment: +1 `format` here takes care of converting your datatypes. You cannot use `os.path.join` on `int`s for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply call the character by its ASCII code. 
(I'm using Python 3.7).

**Example:**

In this case, the ASCII code is 92, you can use [Python's chr() function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) to call the character

[image]

In [this website](https://theasciicode.com.ar/) you can find a list of ASCII codes for more printable characters.

**The code used above:**

```
delimiter = chr(92)

FileName = 'Id' + delimiter + 'TypeOfMachine' + delimiter + 'year' + '_' + 'month' + delimiter + 'year' + '_' + 'month' + '_' + 'day' + '.csv'

print(FileName)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Without importing os.path module you could simply do:

```
 my_path = '\\'.join([Id,TypeOfMachine, year + '_' + month, year + '_' + month + '_' + day + '.csv'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use normal strings like:

```
Id + '/' + TypeOfMachine + '/' + year + '_' + month + '/' + year + '_' + month + '_' + day + '.csv'
```