# Force odd number of backslashes in dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, backslash

I am specifically looking to print this in the terminal `{'Name': '[{\\\"test\\\\":\\\"somedata\\\"}]'}`

So far I can get 2 slashes or 4 slashes but I am not sure how to three slashes.

I tried doing `replace('"','\\\"')`

```
fdsa = {"Name":'[{"test":"somedata"}]'}
fdsa["Name"] = fdsa["Name"].replace('"','\\\"')
print(fdsa)
#{'Name': '[{\\"test\\":\\"somedata\\"}]'}
```

I tried doing `replace('"','\\\\"')`

```
fdsa = {"Name":'[{"test":"somedata"}]'}
fdsa["Name"] = fdsa["Name"].replace('"','\\\\"')
print(fdsa)
#{'Name': '[{\\\\"test\\\\":\\\\"somedata\\\\"}]'}
```

I tried doing `replace('"',r'\"')`

```
fdsa = {"Name":'[{"test":"somedata"}]'}
fdsa["Name"] = fdsa["Name"].replace('"',r'\"')
print(fdsa)
#{'Name': '[{\\"test\\":\\"somedata\\"}]'}
```

I tried doing replace('"',r'\"')

```
fdsa = {"Name":'[{"test":"somedata"}]'}
fdsa["Name"] = fdsa["Name"].replace('"',r'\\"')
print(fdsa)
#{'Name': '[{\\\\"test\\\\":\\\\"somedata\\\\"}]'}
```

I googled as much as I could and came to the conclusion that raw strings can't have an odd number of backslashes [https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-raw-string-escape/#:~:text=source%3A%20raw_string_escape.py-,Raw%20strings%20cannot%20end%20with%20an%20odd%20number%20of%20backslashes,the%20end%20of%20the%20string](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-raw-string-escape/#:%7E:text=source%3A%20raw_string_escape.py-,Raw%20strings%20cannot%20end%20with%20an%20odd%20number%20of%20backslashes,the%20end%20of%20the%20string).

but I am not sure if there is a work around for this?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22792332

[Odd or even number of backslashes and escaped character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441820/odd-or-even-number-of-backslashes-and-escaped-character)

**edit**: I tried using unicode as @TDG mention but it still came out as 3 slashes

```
backslash = '\u005c' 
fdsa = {"Name":'[{"test":"somedata"}]'}
fdsa["Name"] = fdsa["Name"].replace('"',f'{backslash*3}'+'"')
print(fdsa)
```

Comment: Why do you want `"` escaped in a string delimited by `'`?

Comment: I think you are confusing the content of the string with what gets serialized when you `print` a `dict`. Python escapes necessary characters in strings in that circumstance, and in particular it will serialize a literal backslash character as two backslashes. if you parse it again as json or python code it will still contain the correct undoubled number of slashes